Are the unit tangent spaces over hyperbolic surfaces always Seifert?
I saw on Wikipedia (in the geometrization conjecture article) that the unitary tangent space over a surface S with finite volume and genus > 1 is a Seifert manifold.
What if we do not assume that S has finite volume? Has this been studied? I am particularly interested in the case where S has an Anosov geodesic flow.

A Seifert manifold is a sort of generalized fiber bundle over a surface, so actual fiber bundles like unit tangent bundles definitely count.  But more is true: the tangent bundle of an orientable non-closed surface $S$ is trivial, so its unit tangent bundle splits as $S \times S^1$.

Thank you for your anwer. Seems like I confused Seifert manifolds with manifolds that are fibrations over the circle.

Not a research level math question.
